# Javascript to update asp label inside repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a simple page with a repeater containing a single user control.  The user control has 3 properties, price, quantity and item name all of which are bound to a linqData source.  The idea is that a user will enter a quantity in the textbox which will then fire a javascript to update a label control with the total for that row in the repeater.  The script is firing with no issue and is performing the math with no issue, the problem is that it is not updating the asp:label with the newly computed line total.

Here is the code for the user control

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="productName">product name</asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="productPrice" Text="$0.00"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="qty" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="updateLine" />

        </telerik:RadTextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateLine(sender, args) {
        var vBox = $find('<%=qty.ClientID %>');
        var pBox = document.getElementById('<%=productPrice.ClientID%>');
        var newLineTotal = sender.get_value() * pBox.innerText;
        document.getElementById('<%=lblTotal.ClientID%>').textContent = newLineTotal;
            }
</script>
```

I have tried .textContent, .innerHTML, .value and .innerText attributes of the label in my javascript but none of those will set the value.  The alert works fine and displays the properly computed total.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I just can't wrap my head around this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

try just using the id of the label like this

```
document.getElementById('lblTotal').innerText
```

Comment: That will not work because there will be no item by that name on the page at runtime.  However, just for giggles I did do it and it just results in an undefined error.